# Detect changes in the Controls in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I created a function for VBA that return's true or false if all controls in a given UserForm have changes when I try to close the Form without saving changes to the DB.

The code is working fine if I specify a existing Form name in `For Each C In FormName.Controls`, example: `SMSConfig.Controls`.

But I'm trying to make it more dynamic so I can use this function in any form, so I would just need to call the function `Call FuncChanges(True, Me.Name)` in a Close event to make it work, but where I have `FormName` I can't figure it out how to refer the Form that I got its name stored in `Me.Name`.

I get an Invalid Qualified Error for `FormName`

Sorry for my not so great english... Any ideas?

```
Public ChangesOld() As String
Public ChangesNew() As String
Public CtrlCount As Byte

Function FuncChanges(NewChanges As Boolean, FormName As String) As Boolean

    Dim C As Control
    Dim FLG As Boolean

    CtrlCount = 0

    For Each C In FormName.Controls
        If TypeName(C) = "TextBox" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1
        If TypeName(C) = "ComboBox" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1
        If TypeName(C) = "OptionButton" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1
    Next C

    If NewChanges = True Then

        ReDim ChangesNew(1 To CtrlCount)

        CtrlCount = 0
        FLG = False

        For Each C In FormName.Controls
            If TypeName(C) = "TextBox" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1: ChangesNew(CtrlCount) = C.Text
            If TypeName(C) = "ComboBox" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1: ChangesNew(CtrlCount) = C.Text
            If TypeName(C) = "OptionButton" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1: ChangesNew(CtrlCount) = C.Value
        Next C

        For X = LBound(ChangesOld) To UBound(ChangesOld)
            If ChangesNew(X) <> ChangesOld(X) Then
                FLG = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next X

        If FLG = True Then FuncChanges = True Else FuncChanges = False

    Else

        ReDim ChangesOld(1 To CtrlCount)

        CtrlCount = 0

        For Each C In FormName.Controls
            If TypeName(C) = "TextBox" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1: ChangesOld(CtrlCount) = C.Text
            If TypeName(C) = "ComboBox" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1: ChangesOld(CtrlCount) = C.Text
            If TypeName(C) = "OptionButton" Then CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1: ChangesOld(CtrlCount) = C.Value
        Next C

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Pass the actual form instance, not the name: `Function FuncChanges(NewChanges As Boolean, FormInstance As UserForm) As Boolean`

Comment: In your text, you say the function determines "if _all_ controls in a given UserForm have changes", yet your code exits as soon as it detects a single change. Not sure which you're actually after...

Comment: Actually, if you want to determine if _all_ items have changed, you could exit the loop as soon as you've identified one control that has _not_ changed.

Comment: That did it :) Many thanks @Comintern!

Comment: @FreeMan I just need 1 change for it to make the question :) I don't need to go through all.

Comment: No worries and glad it's working for you. A good reason to ensure comments (your question text) describe _why_ you're doing something instead of _what_ you're doing. The _what_ comments will quickly be out of date.